# Getting a tibble without inheriting attributes of model objects?

Tags: r

I'm working with data that has to be accessed and analyzed remotely (you send code, and get output back later on). Since there are limitations on manipulation of data in this environment, I'm trying to get output that I can work with locally, for example passing the estimates of a marginaleffects command to a tibble, which I then dput. However, I have some problems with objects becoming too large since the objects I create contain a lot of extra information, and the system either kills the entire process, or these objects are impossible to dput.

Here is some example data/code for illustration:

```
library(marginaleffects)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(cyl) * hp + wt, data = mtcars)

avg_slopes <- avg_slopes(
  mod,
  variables = "hp",
  by = "cyl",
  newdata = datagridcf(cyl = c(4, 6, 8)))

sum_tibble <- tibble(summary(avg_slopes)) %>% print(n=Inf, width=Inf)

sort(sapply(ls(), function(x) format(object.size(get(x)), unit = 'auto')))
```

The size of the avg_slopes object and the sum_tibble are identical. I have tried various approaches to strip the superfluous information of sum_tibble, but so far, I haven't come up with a good solution.

Just to reiterate, I want to dput the above sum_tibble to then manipulate locally. While this is possible to do with the example data, the actual data contains several million observations, which are indirectly contained as attributes within the tibble I create, which is not possible to dput.

Still being new to R and object based programming, I'm guessing I might miss something very obvious here, but is it possible to prevent the inheritance of attributes so that I only get the "raw" tibble without all information pertaining to the model and the subsequent call to marginaleffects?

Comment: Can't you just remove the problematic attributes (with `attr<-`) in the code you submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hack would be to call `as.list()` and then `as.data.frame()`:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(cyl) * hp + wt, data = mtcars)

s <- avg_slopes(
  mod,
  variables = "hp",
  by = "cyl",
  newdata = datagridcf(cyl = c(4, 6, 8)))

dput(as.data.frame(as.list(s)))
# structure(list(term = c("hp", "hp", "hp"), contrast = c("mean(dY/dX)", 
# "mean(dY/dX)", "mean(dY/dX)"), cyl = structure(1:3, levels = c("4", 
# "6", "8"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(-0.0994659819905642, 
# -0.0213767879958624, -0.0134410254268038), std.error = c(0.034866542828558, 
# 0.0388209266111018, 0.0125137739622503), statistic = c(-2.85276296189294, 
# -0.550651152920941, -1.07409846680551), p.value = c(0.00433409371050051, 
# 0.581872835787401, 0.282778551663534), s.value = c(7.85005393736507, 
# 0.78122419815293, 1.82225539688337), conf.low = c(-0.167803150199961, 
# -0.0974644060000945, -0.0379675717034894), conf.high = c(-0.0311288137811672, 
# 0.0547108300083696, 0.0110855208498819), predicted_lo = c(22.9190325041762, 
# 21.5267112000579, 20.6538481323895), predicted_hi = c(22.9162176168859, 
# 21.5261062369576, 20.65346775137), predicted = c(22.9190325041762, 
# 21.5267112000579, 20.6538481323895)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
# -3L))
```